# Android inflated view not shown if larger than screen

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, horizontal-scrolling

I have a HorizontalScrollView with a RelativeLayout and another relative layout to which I add dynamic views.
If I add a view created using layout inflater and that view is larger than screen it is not displayed.

for example:

```
 View view1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.some_linear_layout, null, false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(6000, 50);
    lp1.leftMargin =500;
    lp1.topMargin = 20;
    view1.setLayoutParams(lp1);
    parentRelativeLayout.addView(view1);

    View view2 =  new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(6000, 50);
    lp2.leftMargin =500;
    lp2.topMargin = 20;
    view2.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    parentRelativeLayout.addView(view2);
```

In this case only view2 is visible, and view1 is not.
Any idea how to make view1 appear?

the parent layout xml is something like:

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/panel1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:minWidth="200dp">
                 <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/panel2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/black">
     </.......
```

I set the width of panel1 and panel2 to 8000px before adding children

Comment: It seems `view2` overlaps `view1`. Add `layout_toRightOf` to `view2` to make it placed to the right of `view1`.

Comment: I want them to overlap. The problem is not the overlap, it is that view1 does not appear at all if the width is larger than screen. I added the 2 in the example is to show that view 2 appears and view 1 not,  even if I leave only one of them and comment the other

Comment: I have also added the parent layout, as someone requested

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was my fault

I had the background defined as

```
<corners
android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
```

that worked if the view was smaller than screen width

changed it to (below) and the background appears now

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/red" />
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```